# Deploying Angular Universal to Azure or Netify (dist and dist-server folders)

Tags: angular, azure, angular-universal, netlify

I have an Anugular 6 app which uses Universal.

Universal/server side rendering works locally.

I am wondering how to deploy this app to azure. Considering that it has two dist folders (dist, dist-server).

I can setup an Azure web site and add the dist folder but I'm not sure how to deploy both folders to enable server side rendering.

I am also considering using Netlify for hosting.

How do you set up both folders on these providers? Has anyone successfully done this?

Comment: Netlify would only be able to host the frontend (probably the `dist` folder).  You could use Netlify's proxying (https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#proxying) to speak to the back end on any provider (azure/heroku/etc)

Comment: @fool could you please detail how exactly you would do this?? I have posted a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036914/deploy-angular-uniserval-project-to-netlify

Comment: I can give you a very long response if you write in to our helpdesk, support@netlify.com, @smokey dawson .  too long to fit in a comment here.

Answer (score -1):

/server.ts - remap your folders to be dist/browser and dist/server.

```
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
const APP_NAME = 'browser';

const {
  AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  LAZY_MODULE_MAP
} = require(`./dist/server/main`);

// other code //

app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, APP_NAME));

// Static Assets
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, APP_NAME), {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));
```

update angluar.json

```
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
```

and

```
 "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
```

with Netlify you can specify your branch and the build command you want to run on deploy - eg 'yarn run prod:ssr' which should replicate what you have working locally.